# Set SDK and JDK in Unity this get an error message

Tags: android, path, jdk, sdk, unity3d

I try already half day in Unity to get to run an AR App with Vuforia. The app should be for an ODG R-7 glasses (on Android basis). If I click on "Build and Run", then I will be prompted to specify a JDK and SDK path which I have done.

Then I got an error message for both (SDK and JDK) and could eliminate the error for the SDK (i have unname the SDK Folder). The error with the JDK, however, I can not fix -.-

I have test the path to JDK version 121. 
I have checked in the windows console the Java version and since I have 1.8.0_74. Then I changed the path to Unity (Edit / Preferences ... / External Tools) into the path for 1.8.0_74 and I've tested it again. You can see the mistakes in the pictures. The path to version 121 is still displayed.

Now i rename the jdk 121 in 74 and now the Windows console say i have jdk 121 but the error remains.

Does somebody still have an idea?

PS: I dont no how to change the Java Version, than i have unname the Folder :P
Edit: now i have Change my Java Version clearly

[Error One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkMO4.jpg)
[Error Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p77RY.jpg)

Comment: Somehow you have both ``\`` and `/` in your Java command

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not. Unity created the message somewhat strange. The paths I have set correctly, but thanks (:  I have change the paths  
C:/Development/Android/Sdk
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121

Comment: Why tag with `ubuntu-unity`? Your paths are Windows paths.